# Setting the cursor's location in JavaFX

Tags: input, javafx

Is there a way to set the cursor's location in JavaFX while the window is in focus? I've searched the possibility of the Scene's cursor object, but that leads to a dead end.

Comment: Heads up: JavaFX is completely useless for anything that isn't basic or requires more than 10 FPS (made up figure). OpenGL is recommended.

Comment: What really? For my PC it does really well...

Comment: It wasn't designed for games. Anything that requires any decent amount of rendering won't work out very well. You should check out LibGDX.

Comment: I was looking at that however I never found any good tutorials... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the function `mouseMove(int x, int y)` like this:

`new Robot().mouseMove(150, 200);` ?

Source: [Robot (Java 2 Platform SE 5.0)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html)